# How to get url parameters as a list in Django?

Tags: django, django-urls

I want to get url parameters as list in django. Say for example, I will add each parameters to url as;

`mydomain.com/param1/param2/param3/.../paramx`

Where each param may be existed or not. For example a link may be;
`mydomain.com/param1/param3/param4/...`

So my question is, How can I get list of params in Django?

I tried handling parameters manually but since they are seperated it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: is there a reason why you want it to be path variables? it could make more sense to have them as query variables then you could read the querydict in the view

Comment: @bb4L thats because I want it to be more human readable and optimized for search engine.

Answer (score 0):

looking at the docs you should be able to use `path` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/#path-converters

you then most likely have the path/string `param1/param2...` as a variable on your view